# What is a Meteor.autorun in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, autorun

I want know about Meteor.autorun in meteor. And why they are being Used? What are the features they provided?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of meteor? `Meteor.autorun` has been changed to `Deps.autorun` for a while now

Comment: FWIW, `Meteor.autorun` was changed to `Deps.autorun` and after that changed to `Tracker.autorun`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor.autorun has been changed to Deps.autorun. Deps is Meteor's dependency tracking system, and Deps.autorun will automatically re-run a function whenever dependencies (session variables, db queries, etc) are changed.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor Deps is a new reactive programming system that is incredibly simple and lightweight. Deps.autorun is a callback function associated with a reactive variable which immediately runs the function passed to it when the variable changes.

Review the Meteor manual for a through explanation
http://manual.meteor.com/